# mimic linux grep -w in perl grep

Tags: linux, perl

Grep in perl gives me all the matched lines with the regular expression.

For ex-

```
{
    my @FAMILY_MAP= ("A2LVLX","LVLX","O2LVLX");
    my $search="LVLX";
    my @match = grep (/ALVL/, @FAMILY_MAP);
    print @match;
 }
```

Here my expected output is LVLX but i get all the three elements in the array.
Which is expected behaviour in the Linux terminal too(if grep LVLX is done on a file containing the three words). But i have to used grep -w "LVLX" in the terminal to get LVLX as the output.
I need a way to replicate the same using perl grep. Any hints?

Comment: Your description doesn't match what your code does - it doesn't produce any output as none of the input strings match `/ALVL/`. Please update one or the other to bring them into line.

Comment: Please note that ALLCAPS variable names are by convention reserved for package variables or globals in Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep -w` matches the string only when it appears as a whole word. For that, you need to use the word boundary (`\b`) escape sequence in your regex.

```
my @family_map = ("A2LVLX","LVLX","O2LVLX");
my $search = 'LVLX';
my @match = grep (/\b$search\b/, @family_map);
print "@match";
```

**Update:** Alternatively, if you know the elements of your array will all be individual words, then just use `eq`.

```
my @match = grep( $_ eq $search, @family_map);
```

Comment: I was thinking I should have read the docs, I was sure mine wasn't quite right... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an exact match, you need to tell it. Your pattern `/LVLX/` matches strings that contain the pattern, because you have not anchored it.

There are two ways to do this. Either you anchor your pattern like this

```
my @match = grep(/^ALVL$/, @FAMILY_MAP);
```

or you use the block form of `grep` and do an equality check, which is faster in older Perls (very new Perls have this optimized, but I don't remember in which version that was introduced)

```
my @match = grep { $_ eq 'ALVL' } @FAMILY_MAP;
```

Both will give you the same output.